# Trouble when selecting a column to update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to update the column `apikey` in the table `users`
But as i run the query from PHP it seems to set the rank to 0 and doesn't change something on the apikey at all.
Here is the code.

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    require_once('includes/db.php');
    require_once('includes/init.php');
    if(!($user->LoggedIn())){
        header('location: login.php');
        die();
    }
    if(!($user->isAdmin($odb))){
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    if(!($user->notBanned($odb))){
        header('location: logout.php');
        die();
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $SQLGetInfo = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
    $SQLGetInfo->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
    $userInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $username = $userInfo['username'];
    $password = $userInfo['password'];
    $api = $userInfo['apikey'];
    $email = $userInfo['email'];
    $rank = $userInfo['rank'];
    $membership = $userInfo['membership'];
    $status = $userInfo['status'];

?>
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($_POST['rBtn'])){
                                        $sql = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM `keys` WHERE `number` = :id");
                                        $sql->execute(array(':id' => $id));
                                        header('location: users.php');
                                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['updateBtn'])){
                                        $update = false;
                                        if($username != $_POST['api']){
                                            if(ctype_alnum($_POST['api']) && strlen($_POST['api']) >= 4 && strlen($_POST['api']) <= 35){
                                                $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE  `apikey`.`users` SET  `apikey` =  :api WHERE `users`.`ID` = :id");
                                                $SQL->execute(array(':api' => $_POST['api'], ':apikey' => $id));
                                                $update = true;
                                                $username = $_POST['username'];
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><p>Key has to be alphanumeric 4 > 35</p></div>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
                                            $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = :password WHERE `ID` = :id");
                                            $SQL->execute(array(':password' => SHA1($_POST['password']), ':id' => $id));
                                            $update = true;
                                            $password = SHA1($_POST['password']);
                                        }
                                        if($email != $_POST['email']){
                                            if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                                                $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `email` = :email WHERE `ID` = :id");
                                                $SQL->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email'], ':id' => $id));
                                                $update = true;
                                                $email = $_POST['email'];
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><p>You entered an invalid email!</p></div>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if($rank != $_POST['rank']){
                                            $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `rank` = :rank WHERE `ID` = :id");
                                            $SQL->execute(array(':rank' => $_POST['rank'], ':id' => $id));
                                            $update = true;
                                            $rank = $_POST['rank'];
                                        }
                                        if($membership != $_POST['plan']){
                                            if($_POST['plan'] == 0){
                                                $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `expire` = '0', `membership` = '0' WHERE `ID` = :id");
                                                $SQL->execute(array(':id' => $id));
                                                $update = true;
                                                $membership = $_POST['plan'];
                                            } else {
                                                $getPlanInfo = $odb->prepare("SELECT `unit`,`length` FROM `plans` WHERE `ID` = :plan");
                                                $getPlanInfo->execute(array(':plan' => $_POST['plan']));
                                                $plan = $getPlanInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                                $unit = $plan['unit'];
                                                $length = $plan['length'];
                                                $newExpire = strtotime("+{$length} {$unit}");
                                                $updateSQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `expire` = :expire, `membership` = :plan WHERE `id` = :id");
                                                $updateSQL->execute(array(':expire' => $newExpire, ':plan' => $_POST['plan'], ':id' => $id));
                                                $update = true;
                                                $membership = $_POST['plan'];
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if($status != $_POST['status']){
                                            $SQL = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `status` = :status WHERE `ID` = :id");
                                            $SQL->execute(array(':status' => $_POST['status'], ':id' => $id));
                                            $update = true;
                                            $status = $_POST['status'];
                                        }
                                        if($update == true){
                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><p>The key has been updated. You will be taken back to the key-manager!</p></div>';
                                            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=edit-user-api.php">';
                                        } else {
                                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><p>Nothing seems to have changed..</p></div>';
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['clearlBtn'])){
                                        $SQL = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM `loginip` WHERE `username` = :username");
                                        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><p>Login logs were deleted from the account.</p></div>';
                                    }
                                ?>
```

Comment: Your query params are `:api` & `:id`, so why is your `->execute()` params `:api` & `:apikey`?

Comment: Also, you have `if($username != $_POST['api'])`, but I don't see where you define `$username` before that.

Comment: Is your database `apikey`? As you have `\`apikey\`.\`users\`` in the `apikey` update query, but just `\`users\`` in all the other queries.

Comment: I also don't see where you define `$id`, in addition to `$username`, so there is code you are not showing AND a lot of code that is here that has nothing to do with your question. So you haven't even narrowed it down to what is needed to address this issue.

Comment: I see that you updated your question with **more** code. That helps with the question about the defined variables. So what about my questions about the query params, and the database/table name difference?

Comment: I find it odd that you have `$username = $userInfo['username'];` but instead of comparing to `$_POST['username']`, you compare to `$_POST['api']` in `if($username != $_POST['api'])`